# Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Trying to get a list of users associated with an event. Here are my eloquent models:

User.php:

```
public function fbevents()
{
    $this->belongsToMany('Fbevent', 'fbevent_user');
}
```

Fbevent.php:

```
public function users()
{
    $this->belongsToMany('User', 'fbevent_user);
}
```

I get this error when I try to find the list:

```
$event = Fbevent::find(10);
var_dump($event->users->lists('userId'));
```

I've set up a pivot table in the db with the following migration:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('fbevent_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('fbevent_id')->references('id')->on('fbevents')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->timestamps();
```

And added an entry in the fbevent_user table with fbevent_id = 10 and user_id = 1.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to return a result from your relations

```
public function fbevents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Fbevent', 'fbevent_user');
}
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'fbevent_user');
}
```

Comment: thanks got same problem, I forgot to add return. must be the effect of too much coffee XD